# How can I read a file and convert the content in [[Char]],? - IO String to String

Tags: list, haskell

I have a file like this:

```
001
002
003
004
```

and I need construct a list ["001","002","003","004"]

I tried this

```
map (splitOn "\n") (readFile "file.txt")
```

but I'm receiving the message:

```
Couldn't match expected type `[[Char]]'
            with actual type `IO String'
In the return type of a call of `readFile'
In the second argument of `map', namely `(readFile "file.txt")'
In the expression: map (splitOn "") (readFile "file.txt")
```

I understand the reason, I need a [[Char]] in the second argument of map and the readFile returns an IOString, but I don't know how make the conversion

**EDIT**

I did what was suggested but I continues receiving a error message:

code:

```
main = do
    fileContents <- readFile "file.txt"
    let modified = map (splitOn "\n") fileContents
    putStrLn modified
```

error:

```
Couldn't match type `Char' with `[Char]'
Expected type: [[Char]]
  Actual type: String
In the second argument of `map', namely `fileContents'
In the expression: map (splitOn "") fileContents
In an equation for `string': string = map (splitOn "") fileContents
```

Comment: I guess `map (splitOn "\n") "001\n002\n"` would yield the same type error. Are you sure you need the `map`? Check the type of `splitOn`.

Comment: You're right. I needn't map. But in the second argument of `splitOn` I need a [[Char]] but the file is IO String. I tried the suggestions but I ever receive the same error

Comment: I got it! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `lines`:

```
fileContents  <- lines <$> readFile "file.txt"
```

It use the fact that `IO` is a `Functor`.